# How can gunicorn handle hundreds of thousands of requests per second for django?

Tags: django, multithreading, gunicorn

From the docs - [How many workers](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#how-many-workers),

DO NOT scale the number of workers to the number of clients you expect to have. Gunicorn should only need 4-12 worker processes to handle hundreds or thousands of requests per second.

Generally we recommend (2 x $num_cores) + 1 as the number of workers to start off with.

From [threads](http://Generally%20we%20recommend%20(2%20x%20$num_cores)%20+%201%20as%20the%20number%20of%20workers%20to%20start%20off%20with.),

The number of worker threads for handling requests.

Run each worker with the specified number of threads.

A positive integer generally in the 2-4 x $(NUM_CORES) range. You’ll want to vary this a bit to find the best for your particular application’s workload.

Now the question is what no of threads and workers can serve hundreds or thousands of requests per second?

Let's say I have a dual-core machine and I set 5 workers and 8 threads. And I can serve 40 concurrent requests?

If I am going to serve hundreds or thousands of requests, I'll need a hundred cores?

this line is very hard to understand:

> Gunicorn should only need 4-12 worker processes to handle hundreds or
> thousands of requests per second.

Answer (score 14):

> Now the question is what no of threads and workers can serve hundreds or thousands of requests per second? Let's say I have a dual-core machine and I set 5 workers and 8 threads. And I can serve 40 concurrent requests?

Yes, with 5 worker processes, each with 8 threads, 40 concurrent requests can be served. How quickly they'll be served on a dual-core box is another question.

> If I am going to serve hundreds or thousands of requests, I'll need a hundred cores?

Not quite. Requests per second is not the same as "concurrent requests".

If each request takes exactly 1 millisecond to handle, then a single worker can serve 1000 RPS. If each request takes 10 milliseconds, a single worker dishes out 100 RPS.

If some requests take 10 milliseconds, others take, say, up to 5 seconds, then you'll need more than one concurrent worker, so the one request that takes 5 seconds does not "hog" all of your serving capability.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. "If some requests take 10 milliseconds, others take, say, up to 5 seconds, then you'll need more than one concurrent worker" 
=> I'm using gthread worker. If I have 5 workers as the example, I can handle 5 x 5-second requests at the same time? Or 1 only since others are blocked?

Comment: Without looking closer into it, I'd imagine each request will likely take up a thread each.

Comment: Let's say, a single request takes 180 seconds to complete then how many workers should I have?

Comment: @SyedMuhammadAsad There's no simple answer. If you have one worker, you can service one such request in 3 minutes. If you have two workers and two such requests come in simultaneously, both workers will be tied up for 3 minutes. Long requests would be better handled by a background worker.